# Updating a MySQL table with a self-referencing column

Tags: mysql, self-reference, self-referencing-table

I have a table (simplified) that looks like this:

```
id     | name   | selfreference | selfreference-name
------ | -------| --------------| ------------------ 
1      | Vienna |               |  
2      | Wien   |               | Vienna
3      | Виена  |               | Vienna
```

The selfreference column refers to the id numbers of the same table. In the above example, both Wien and Виена refer to the same city, so the value of their selfreference column should be equal to 1.

In other words, I need to do something like

```
 update `places` 
 set `places`.`selfreference` = 
 (select `places`.`id` from `places`where `places`.`name` = `places`.`selfreference-name`)
```

but the SELECT statement above is obviously wrong. I am at a loss how to proceed.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

All best,
Tench

Edit: the desired output would look like this:

```
id     | name   | selfreference | selfreference-name
------ | -------| --------------| ------------------ 
1      | Vienna |               |  
2      | Wien   |  1            | Vienna
3      | Виена  |  1            | Vienna
```

Comment: show a proper sample of the result you want obtain

Answer (score 1):

Could be you need a self join

chekc with select

```
select a.*, b.*
from  `places` as a
inner join `places` as b

where b.`name` = a.`selfreference-name`;
```

and then  if the query above  give you the right result

```
update `places` as a
inner join `places` as b
set b.`selfreference` =  ab.`id`
where b.`name` = a.`selfreference-name`;
```

Comment: actually, it's the other way around, but i really couldn't have done it without you.   update places as a
inner join places as b
set b.`selfreference` = a.`id`
where b.`selfreference-name` = a.`name`

Comment: I know this is old, but the first query doesn't look right. If I had to guess, I'd remove the "set" line and add a "b" after "as"

Comment: @Mordechai  .. correct  .. thanks  .. answer  updated  removing the worng set  ..

Answer (score 0):

The following query does the job:

```
UPDATE places p1
INNER JOIN places p2 ON p1.`name` = p2.`selfreference-name`
SET p2.selfreference = p1.id;
```

`p2` -> instance of table `places` which will be updated.

`p1` -> instance of table `places` from where the `id` of the matching `selfreference-name` is taken.

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO BEFORE UPDATING**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/add741/1/0)</kbd>

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO AFTER UPDATING**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/786e6/1/0)</kbd>